# Getting error "Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts'" When trying to run Azure DevOps Multi-Stage Yaml using Self hosted Agent (Windows 2019)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am Getting error

```
##[error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: '5.1.1'. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task agent
```

When trying to run Azure DevOps pipeline using Multi-Stage Yaml using Self hosted Agent (Windows 2019)

**The Yaml:**

```
    - task: AzurePowerShell@5
      displayName: 'Disconnect DEV Function App'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(DEVAzureSvcCon)'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: 'az webapp deployment source delete --resource-group $(DEVResourceGroup) --name $(DEVFunctionAppName)'
        FailOnStandardError: true
        preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '5.1.1'
```

I have tried multiple versions for powershell including "latest" but no dice. I have also RDP'd into the agent servers and have installed az cli on powershell using admin mode and  Install-Module -Name Az  -Scope AllUsers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Though you are using Powershell in your tasks, what you are actually running in the Inline script is az cli. Since you are using a self hosted agent, you’d have to install az cli in your machine and then try.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: I have installed az-cli on the pipeline agent servers. I used Powershell to do it, in administrator mode. Perhaps there is some kind of environmental difference between where the agent works and the common directories of the agent server?